# How to cache data in an Android app?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my app, I need some data that I do not want to request every time from the server.
This dat includes the userId and some array string.
I think I can store the user id in the `SharedPreferences`,
but what about the array?

Is it OK to use static variables?

Comment: updated the answer please check.. update if you got the answer ..

Comment: It's better to use some caching mechanism (Sqlite, ObjectBox, Realm, file, some ORM like Store.io, cache via http client) if you need to store array in prefs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences?rq=1

Comment: You can store arraylist in shared preference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson parse Array to String and save to shared preferences.
When you read String from shared preferences you can use Gson to convert String to Array.
[Gson library](https://github.com/google/gson)

```
ArrayList<String> yourArrayStr = convertArrayToString(yourArray);
SharedPreferences prefs =  context.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE_NAME",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("array_key_name", yourArrayStr);
editor.apply();
```

function: **convertArrayToString**

```
private String convertArrayToString(ArrayList<String> yourArray){
Gson gson = new Gson();
return gson.toJson(yourArray);
}
```

function **convertStringToArray** when you read String from shared preferences

```
private ArrayList<String> convertStringToArray(String yourArrayStr){
Gson gson = new Gson();
return gson.fromJson(yourArrayStr , new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.getType());
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You also can serialize your array to save a array as string in preferences, but keep in mind that if it was big, use Sqllite...

Or you can use the firebase with offline function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a class model. like this

```
public class User implements Serializable {
@SerializedName("id")
private int id;

@SerializedName("array")
private ArrayList<String> array;

//your get/set are here too
```

}

I use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to make my life easier.

Than on your server response save the Json on your SharedPreference

```
SharedPreferencesUtils.write(Constants.Preferences.Keys.USER_DATA, userJson);
```

And finally everytime you need to read this information you use

```
String json = SharedPreferencesUtils.read(Constants.Preferences.Keys.USER_DATA, null);
      User user = new Gson().fromJson(json, User.class);
```

I would load this information on your singleton to use everywhere i need it in the application :)

If you need to update it.. just get the response and save again on your SharedPreference.